# How to target an outer Div when checkbox is checked

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I want to target a div when a checkbox is checked. Can anybody tell me how can I target an outer div when checkbox is checked?

Comment: There is the css pseudo selector `:checked`, but I don't think you can target a parent (outer div) because CSS is cascading and won't traverse up the DOM

Comment: And by target an div you mean what exactly? Css effect? Move the cursor to the element?

Comment: CSS alone _can not_ target an outer (parent) element of a given element. You will have to use javascript to work your way up the element hierarchy until you find the element you want to change. (jquery makes this easy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($('.checkboxClassName').checked) {
    $(this).parent();
}
```

It will target the parent div that the checkbox is inside, you can use more .parent() if tour target is not inside the same parent.
example: if your code is like this:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="target"></div>
      <div class="parent">
        <div class="checkboxDiv">
            <input type="checkbox">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and you want to target the `div.target` you'll need the code like this:

```
    if($('.checkboxClassName').checked) {
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".target").css('background','magenta');
    } else { 
      $(this).parent().parent().parent().find(".target").css('background','cyan');
    }
```

those parents will work like this: `$(this).parent()` = targeting `div.checkboxDiv`

`$(this).parent().parent()` = targeting `div.parent`

...

Comment: *forgot to mention: you'll need jquery.

Comment: `.closest()` could be better if the targeted div is not the direct parent of the checkbox. `$('checkbox.someClass:checked').closest('div.someContainer').doSomething(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Note how this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/zx99mmdn/) highlights the usage in a very simple way:

1. A check box is focused upon (checked).
2. The CSS style :checked catches this occurrence and applies a CSS style to the div contents.

The div can be another element you want, just make sure you play around with the code and adapt it to your needs. Let us know if you need any more help!

Source: [:checked](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/)

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm"> 
<label for="ossm">CSS is Awesome</label>
```

CSS

```
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  color: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
} 
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: #f00;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Edit: I thought you would like a reference to 'how' CSS works here:

1. [Attribute Selector by value](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp)
2. [Element plus Element](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp)
3. ...and in general [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)